# Is there an icon for the word "ICON"?

Tags: icon, symbolism

Is there an icon for the word **icon**?

I am trying to build a website like [flaticon](http://www.flaticon.com/), and made me wonder, is there an icon for icons?

Like there are icons for **settings** or **database**.

Comment: There is no generic icon for icons, no. Why would you need one?

Comment: Something different that came to mind for me was something like an ancient civilisation icon (e.g Mayan figure)

Comment: Is this a philosophical question? n_n

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is no icon for the word "icon", I would use shapes to describe that word like The Noun Project's logo.

[image]

Comment: Hello Onur! Eh, that's bad to hear :( We do have some requirements to our answers, but those requirements should not be enforced in an aggressive tone. If any user (even a mod like myself) treats you rudely, don't hesitate to flag their post. This answer does look good to me.
Officially, I'd have to delete / edit out your complaint and forward you to meta to discuss it--because that's the proper place for well, meta-discussion. If our general tone is of an issue to you, I'd love to see your meta post about it. Please keep contributing!

Comment: Thank you Vincent, you can definitely delete/edit my complaint. I'll write a meta post about it.

Answer (score -3):

This is an icon for "icon" in dev tools (Visual Studio):D

[image]

Comment: That isn't an icon for "Icon", it is an icon for an icon *file*. And I doubt that would be understood to mean icon in any situation.

Comment: Would be a better answer if you could expand and show where else this symbol is used... rather specific in this case