# What shape can I use to make an icon for "icons" page?

Tags: shapes, icon, interface-design

fellow designers,

I'm working on a toolbar, and all the triggers use only icons. One of these triggers opens a modal where users can choose an icon. However, I'm unsure about the best shape for the icon representing "Icons."
In summary, what's the ideal shape for the "Icons" icon?

I understand that there are similar questions ([like this one →](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/76837/is-there-an-icon-for-the-word-icon)), but none of them helped me figure this out.

Any idea or suggestion is hugely appreciated!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Perhaps try [The Noun Project](https://thenounproject.com/search/icons/?q=icons). There are a few there which may be suitable.

Comment: If you're going to use icons that aren't universally well-known, I suggest that you [use labels](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/icon-usability/).

Comment: what will the icons that are selected be used for?

Answer (score 0):

You need to zoom out, leave the specific and go abstract. You are trying to represent **a group of concepts** under a single topic.

- https://thenounproject.com/icon/network-1239643/
- https://thenounproject.com/icon/cells-3211013/
- https://thenounproject.com/icon/icons-571295/
- https://thenounproject.com/icon/network-6086158/